# Constexpr wrapper over C array with std::vector-like constructors

Tags: c++, arrays, metaprogramming, c++14, constexpr

I need a constexpr wrapper over a C array or a `std::array` with some extra constructors (similar to `std::vector` constructors):

```
template<class T, int N>
struct wrapper {
  T data[N];

  constexpr wrapper(int s);         // a
  constexpr wrapper(int j, int k);  // b

  constexpr wrapper(...values...)   // c
  : data(...values...) {} 
};
```

I am trying to get the same behavior as the `std::vector` constructors, that is:

```
constexpr wrapper<T,2> w(1);   // calls a
constexpr wrapper<T,2> w(1,2); // calls b
constexpr wrapper<T,2> w{1};   // calls c
constexpr wrapper<T,2> w{1,2}; // calls c
```

Note 1: a perfect forwarding constructor:

```
template<class... Args>
constexpr wrapper(T&& t, Args&&... args) 
: data(std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
```

would win over the other constructors.

Note 2: `T[N]/std::array<T,N>` have no `std::initializer_list<T>` constructors so the following doesn't work either:

```
constexpr wrapper(std::initializer_list<T> v) : data(std::move(v)) {}
```

Note 3: if the values are not assigned in the constructor initialization list the wrapper type won't work in constant expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just use `index_sequence` and a delegating constructor:

```
  constexpr wrapper(std::initializer_list<T> v)
    : wrapper(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}, v) {}
private:
  template<std::size_t... Is> constexpr wrapper(
      std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::initializer_list<T> v)
    : data{v.begin()[Is]...} {}
```

This works because per **[support.initlist.access]** the accessors of `initializer_list` are `constexpr`; its iterator type is `E const*` so we can access any defined member of its array at compile time.

Note that if you supply a too-short braced-init-list (such that `v.size() < N`) then this will fail; at compile time if used in a constant-expression, and with undefined behavior otherwise.  Here's a solution, default-constructing `T` if allowed, and throwing an exception otherwise:

```
  constexpr static T too_short(std::true_type) { return {}; }
  T too_short(std::false_type) {
    throw std::invalid_argument("braced-init-list too short"); }
  template<std::size_t... Is> constexpr wrapper(
      std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::initializer_list<T> v)
    : data{v.size() > Is ? v.begin()[Is]
        : too_short(std::is_default_constructible<T>{})...} {}
```

If you want the initialization to always fail when called with a too-short braced-init-list, just replace the right-hand branch of the conditional operator with a throw-expression:

```
  constexpr wrapper(std::initializer_list<T> v)
    : wrapper(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}, v.size() == N ? v
        : throw std::invalid_argument("braced-init-list incorrect length")) {}
private:
  template<std::size_t... Is> constexpr wrapper(
      std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::initializer_list<T> v)
    : data{v.begin()[Is]...} {}
```

It is not possible other than in a constant-expression portably to detect at compile time that the braced-init-list is too short (or too long!), because `initializer_list` hides that information from the type system.

[Full example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8584e3c0e12fba7e).